# Merging two Pandas Dataframes using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm new to Python and Pandas but I try to use Pandas Dataframes to merge two dataframes based on regular expression.

I have one dataframe with some 2 million rows. This table contains data about cars but the model name is often specified in - lets say - a creative way, e.g. 'Audi A100', 'Audi 100', 'Audit 100 Quadro', or just 'A 100'. And the same for other brands. This is stored in a column called "Model". In a second model I have the manufacturer.

| Index | Model | Manufacturer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A 100 | Audi |
| 1 | A100 Quadro | Audi |
| 2 | Audi A 100 | Audi |
| ... | ... | ... |

To clean up the data I created about 1000 regular expressions to search for some key words and stored it in a dataframe called 'regex'. In a second column of this table I save the manufacture. This value is used in a second step to validate the result.

| Index | RegEx | Manufacturer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | .* A100 .* | Audi |
| 1 | .* A 100 .* | Audi |
| 2 | .* C240 .* | Mercedes |
| 3 | .* ID3 .* | Volkswagen |

I hope you get the idea.

As far as I understood, the Pandas function "merge()" does not work with regular expressions. Therefore I use a loop to process the list of regular expressions, then use the "match" function to locate matching rows in the car DataFrame and assign the successfully used RegEx and the suggested manufacturer.

I added two additional columns to the cars table 'RegEx' and 'Manufacturer'.

```
for index, row in regex.iterrows():
    cars.loc[cars['Model'].str.match(row['RegEx']),'RegEx'] = row['RegEx']
    cars.loc[cars['Model'].str.match(row['RegEx']),'Manufacturer'] = row['Manfacturer']
```

I learnd 'iterrows' should not be used for performance reasons. It takes 8 minutes to finish the loop, what isn't too bad. However, is there a better way to get it done?

Kind regards
Jiriki

Comment: I'm afraid that with one regex per row you don't have a choice but to loop. Eventually, you could reduce the operations by caching or performing only once the search if there are duplicated regexes

Comment: What do you want in the merged dataframe? Can you show a small example?

Comment: What do you want in the merged dataframe? Can you show a small example?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if it would be faster (I'll be glad, if you would test it), but it doesn't use iterrows():

```py
regex.groupby(["RegEx", "Manufacturer"])["RegEx"]\
    .apply(lambda x: cars.loc[cars['Model'].str.match(x.iloc[0])])
```

EDIT: Code for reproduction:

```py
cars = pd.DataFrame({"Model": ["A 100", "A100 Quatro", "Audi A 100", "Passat V", "Passat Gruz"],
                         "Manufacturer": ["Audi", "Audi", "Audi", "VW", "VW"]})

regex = pd.DataFrame({"RegEx": [".*A100.*", ".*A 100.*", ".*Passat.*"],
                      "Manufacturer": ["Audi", "Audi", "VW"]})

#Output:
#                           Model       Manufacturer
#RegEx      Manufacturer            
#.*A 100.*  Audi    0       A 100       Audi
#                   2       Audi A 100  Audi
#.*A100.*   Audi    1       A100 Quatro Audi
#.*Passat.* VW      3       Passat V    VW
#                   4       Passat Gruz VW
```

Comment: Hello Daniel, thank you for your answer. I tried it and it takes longer than 10 minutes to finish the command. However, I doesn't show the expected result either. Maybe I made a mistake. I will try again next week.